# Visual Studio SQL Server Data Tools and supported frameworks

Tags: .net, visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools

We been asked, by our department to uninstall .NET Frameworks 4 to 4.6 as they are no longer supported.

However, this has also removed the SQL Server Data Tools that we need for an upcoming project on Azure/Data Factory.

So my main questions are:

- Is the framework the same as having the framework installed?
- If it is the same then how do we install SQL Server data tools, without installing the unsupported frameworks.

Comment: The latest version of SSDT (for Visual Studio 2022) runs on Framework 4.7.2, iirc. This suggests you are using an older version of it.

Comment: The consultants who are helping the have said that 2022 is not fully compatible with something (I think that integration with devops).

Comment: Well then, looking at SSDT for Visual Studio 2019 it seems you do need .Net Framework 4 - 4.6 installed.

Comment: Keeping older versions of .Net is not problematic on development/build machines. Usage of tools that use previous versions also not problematic. Its just the development of future tools using those version should not be done. The simplest solution is to tell the powers that be, to keep it on and keep the tools, but no development towards those versions will occur.